# Finding the inverse laplace transformation

Tags: laplace-transform, control-theory

There is a transfer function as below:

$$
  \begin{equation}
    G(s) = \dfrac{4s}{s^2 + 1}
  \end{equation}
$$

Now I would like to find its output inverse laplace transform with input as below:

$$
  u(t) = sint
$$

Below is how I attempted to find the inverse laplace transformation:

$$
  \begin{align*}
     y(t) & = \mathscr{L^{-1}}[\dfrac{4s}{s^2 + 1} * \dfrac{1}{s^2 + 1}] \\ & = \mathscr{L^{-1}}[\dfrac{4s}{(s^2+1)^2}]
  \end{align*}
$$

However, I am not sure how to take apart the fraction to make it apply the laplace transform sheet that I know. Below is another approach that I found:

$$
  \mathscr{L^{-1}}[sF(s)] = f'(t) + \mathscr{L^{-1}}f(0) 
$$

But, this seems quite weird to me as this still requires me to find the transform of

$$
  \mathscr{L^{-1}}[\dfrac{4}{(s^2 + 1)^2}]
$$

which seems no much help to me, and I did not see how to apply inverse laplace transform directly on this.

Can anyone point out what I have misunderstood? Thank you for your time and advice.

Comment: Have you considered using the _time multiplication_ / _frequency differentiation_ rule? [Relevant Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4197586/laplace-transform-of-t2-cos-omega-t)

Comment: The rule you mentioned looks like the approach I listed in the post. I will check that out now.

Comment: @RollenS.D'Souza You are right. I did not aware of this rule much in the past, and it feels like not that straight forward, I think I will figure out soon. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know that the Laplace transform of $sin(t)$ is given by:

$$
  \begin{align*}
     \mathscr{L}[\sin(t)] = \dfrac{}{s^2 + ^2} = F(s) \\
  \end{align*}
$$

Based on the  *time multiplication / frequency differentiation rule* that Rollen mentioned, the Laplace Transform can be written as:

$$
  \begin{align*}
     \mathscr{L}[t \sin(t)] & = -\dfrac{d}{ds}(\dfrac{}{s^2 + ^2}) \\ & = -\dfrac{0 * (s^2 + ^2) - (2s)}{(s^2 + ^2)^2} = \dfrac{2s}{(s^2 + ^2)^2}
  \end{align*}
$$

Therefore, the provided inverse Laplace transform is as below:

$$
  \begin{align*}
     y(t) = \mathscr{L^{-1}}\left[\dfrac{4s}{(s^2 +1)^2}\right] = 2t \sin(t)
  \end{align*}
$$